# Cannot find tools.jar Java CentOS

Tags: java, jar, centos, profiling, tools.jar

I'm trying to find where tools.jar file on CentOS 6.
People are saying they can locate their tools.jar in /java/jre/lib/tools.jar but mine is nowhere to be found.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/e1au9v9a12u5fk5/Screenshot%202015-01-02%2023.54.50.png?dl=0
When I type "locate tools.jar" it returns no results.

```
[root@ns504063 lib]# java -version
java version "1.7.0_71"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.3.2.el6_6-x86_64 u71-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

[root@ns504063 lib]# which java
/usr/bin/java
```

Thanks in advance, toby.

Comment: `ls -ln /usr/bin/java`

Comment: @JigarJoshi I've typed "which java", its in teh question

Comment: @JigarJoshi [root@ns504063 lib]# ls -ln /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 0 0 22 Jan  2 18:36 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java

Comment: @JigarJoshi http://pastebin.com/W2taZ244 Pastebin :)

Comment: `ls /usr/lib/jvm/jre`

Comment: @JigarJoshi http://pastebin.com/ujN35F1q 2nd Pastebin

Comment: `which javac` (I don't think you have JDK installed)

Comment: @JigarJoshi Returns "/usr/bin/javac", visiting this directory, says "-bash: cd: /usr/bin/javac: Not a directory". How do I go about installing the JDK for my version? Thanks

Comment: you have centOS 64 bit ?

Comment: download [jdk-7u71-linux-x64.tar.gz](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) and extract it and set your PATH variable in your `~/.bashrc`

Comment: @JigarJoshi Extract it in what folder? What line do I exactly need to add to the ~/.bashrc? Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: I would usually extract it in `~/tools/`, if you just need `tools.jar` then you don't need to worry about setting `PATH`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to have JDK installed (but JRE), [JDK contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdkfiles.html) `tools.jar`, So download [[jdk-7u71-linux-x64.tar.gz]](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) and extract it